# GroupBy method into C# based on SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

I have basic sql query:

```
  select AutoName,LastName, count(Type)  
  from test_view
  group by LastName,AutoName
```

Into C# I'm doing:

```
public List<test_view> GroupExample()
{
    testViewClassDataContext tv = new testViewClassDataContext();

    var q9 = tv.test_views.GroupBy(item => new {ln = item.LastName, an = item.AutoName })
        .Select(p => new
        {
            ln = p.Key.ln,
            an = p.Key.an,
            count = p.Count(x => x.Type != null) //added from answers
        }).ToList();

    return q9;
}
```

How to write properly count and display data as I have into my sql query?

**Update**: Error after added count line:

[image]

Comment: `.Select(p => new test_view ...`

Comment: This seems to be similar issue from before.. anonymous class error, isn't it?

Comment: Something like this: `count = p.Select(x => x.Type).Distinct().Count()`, or if you don't need the counting of *unique* values, just this: `count = p.Count()`

Comment: @Maarten: afaik, a `Count(column)` does *not* count the number of distinct elements, but the number of non-NULLs.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That was it, thanx. Then it would be `count = p.Count(x => x.Type != null)`

Comment: @Maarten: yes, afaik (well I'm not an expert :) ).

Comment: I did: count = p.Count(x => x.Type != null), but into my "return q9" is erorr about anonymous Types

Comment: @4est: can you show the exact error message.

Comment: @4est: but the *result* is not a list of `test_view`s... It is a new (anonymous) type.

Comment: how to change it to correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LINQ query like:

```
var q9i = from view in tv.test_views                                // FROM test_view
          group view by new { view.LastName, view.AutoName } into g // GROUP BY LastName, AutoName
          select new { g.Key.AutoName, g.Key.LastName,              // SELECT AutoName, LastName
                       Count = g.Where(x => x.Type != null).Count() }; // COUNT(Type)
var q9 = q9i.ToList();
```

This is valid C# (as far as I can tell) and furthermore looks more like the SQL query (which can be useful for (small) revisits).

That being said your query, regardless whether it is in this syntax or the one with function calls and lambda expressions, will return a list of anonymous objects. A problem is that you cannot return it (without loss of type information).

A potential solution is to define a class, like `QueryResult`:

```
public class QueryResult {

    public QueryResult() {
    }

    public String ln { get; set; }
    public String an { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can alter the method to return a `List<QueryResult>`, so:

```
public List<QueryResult> GroupExample() {
    // ...
}
```

and transform the query a bit:

```
var q9i = from view in tv.test_views                                // FROM test_view
          group view by new { view.LastName, view.AutoName } into g // GROUP BY LastName, AutoName
          select new QueryResult { g.Key.AutoName, g.Key.LastName,              // SELECT AutoName, LastName
                       Count = g.Where(x => x.Type != null).Count() }; // COUNT(Type)
```

**Or, you can return `List<object>`**:

```
public List<object> GroupExample() {
    // ...
}
```

and return the anonymous type:

```
var q9i = from view in tv.test_views                                // FROM test_view
          group view by new { view.LastName, view.AutoName } into g // GROUP BY LastName, AutoName
          select new { g.Key.AutoName, g.Key.LastName,              // SELECT AutoName, LastName
                       Count = g.Where(x => x.Type != null).Count() }; // COUNT(Type)
var q9 = q9i.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Comment: thank Willem I will also try yours, but I want to did as into my example

Comment: @4est: but I don't see why you don't want to use the special LINQ query syntax. This is valid C# code and furthermore the compiler will convert it to calls, etc. It is cleaner and thus easier to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: when I'm trying your solution also I'm getting the same "return" error

Comment: I tried " select new test_view" or " select new test_view()" and still: anonymous types

Comment: I saw that, but I don't want to create seperate class.....as I will be have a lot of query's

Comment: @4est: you can also return a `List<object>`, but then you will lose some type information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143876/discussion-between-4est-and-willem-van-onsem).